# NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'product' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['product/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']

Tags: django, backend, slug

Hi I'm learning Django and I'm very new at this.
I want URLs like this: [www.mysite.com/product/product-1](http://www.mysite.com/product/product-1) but I don't know it's not working

models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     price = models.FloatField()
     category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=6)
slug = models.SlugField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("orders:product", kwargs={
        'slug': self.slug
    })
```

views.py

```
class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
      model = Item
      template_name = "product.html"
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import HomeView, ItemDetailView, checkout

urlpatterns = [
    path("", HomeView.as_view(), name="home"),
    path("product/<slug>/", ItemDetailView.as_view(), name="product"),
    path("checkout/", checkout, name="checkout")
]
```

Comment: can u explain what u want to achive , so that i could either suggest a new method

Comment: have you added `product-1` as slug in your product?

Comment: Yeah I've added product-1 slug in the my product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how you get the slug in your url.

```
path("product/<slug:slug>/", ItemDetailView.as_view(), name="product"),
```

Comment: Well thats the way you pass slug through url. You method looks alrite. Is orders your app name and did you import reverse.

Comment: Yeah! The project name is pinocchioecom and the app name is orders. And I did import reverse

Comment: How are you doing the reverse in your html template ?

Comment: ```
<strong>
                    <a href="{{ item.get_absolute_url }}" class="dark-grey-text">{{ item.title }}</a>
                  </strong>
```